# Looking for a connect-the-dots game generator

Tags: html, game, flash

I am working on a project where we would like to have an interactive connect-the-dots game on our website. Is there a (preferably free) app that can create a customized game like this? Functionality I'm looking for is pretty basic: I'd like to be able to use my own reference pictures, place the dots in sequence, and when the puzzle is completed, fade the original picture underneath the finished puzzle.

The end result could be either Flash or HTML5. So far I've only found utilities that will output static files (such as a PDF) for printing.

There is [this tutorial](http://mehdi.biz/blog/2010/02/26/having-fun-with-jquery-and-html-5/), which accomplishes something similar to what I'm looking for, but I really don't have the time to dig into the code to make it work for myself, which is why I'm asking here.

[This Flash-based demonstration](http://hanamidesign.com/laboratory/connect-dots-flash-game-creation-tool/) is not actually functional for uploading images, creating puzzles, etc., but the concept is in line with what I'm looking for.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions!

Comment: Are you sure you are asking for a software recommendation? It seems unclear to me whether you're looking for a piece of advice or a piece of software. [Flashgot](http://flashgot.net/) is an extension for Firefox that makes it easy to download Flash applets, if this may help.

Comment: @VicAche, sorry for the ambiguity; I was referenced here from Stack Overflow, but I just edited my question to more clearly reflect the aims of this forum.

Comment: The demo you provided is not flash based, but HTML5/jQuery based, so Flashgot won't do.

Comment: Some links seem to be broken now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://www.ohmydots.com . It has a connect the dots game creator where anyone can create their game out of any picture. It is free, HTML5 based, and can be played online. The way it works is exactly like you want (once the player links all the dots, the original picture appears underneath the puzzle).
Without much effort, you can create one or many games and embed them on your website.

Cheers,

Comment: OP asked for software that "can create a customized game" – not to integrate "some game". Does your suggestion meet that requirement?

Comment: Yes, at www.ohmydots.com you can create your own connect the dots games.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please **[edit]** your answer to include that – and also how the other requirements (e.g. Output being Flash or HTML5, uploading your own images to be used) are met?